# MySQL merging multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a logging database where I archive every week new tables like :

```
log_20170823
log_20170816
log_20170809
log_20170802
log_20170726
```

How can I easily merge all these tables into 1 table in another server (archived) for query simplicity. The current procedures all uses the "log" table.

I mean, I know I can use "UNION" but I want this to be dynamic, because the archiving of the table itself is dynamic, meaning I won't know the name of the archived tables necessarily.

So far I was thinking on doing a

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'log_%'
```

And then save result into an array, foreach the array and build a dynamic string with the names of the tables I'd need to join/union/merge.

Is there any other way directly in mySQL to do so?
My way seams sketchy and I'm worrying about the performance of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As this is an Off Line process, surely the performance is of little importance

Comment: unusual table design to start with, why not just one log table? a table can have billions of rows

Comment: not really, there's a reason why it's like that. I'm not explaining it because it's out of context. But that's what I have to deal with at the moment.

Comment: Have you looked into partitioning?